# How to load and display any video in my computer to a UWP (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I am stuck trying to implement a feature for an UWP application that I am making. I have a MediaElement declared in my XAML doc like this:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="_media" AutoPlay="True" IsLooping="True" Margin="0,0,8,227" AreTransportControlsEnabled="true" RenderTransformOrigin="0.499,0.41" >
        <MediaElement.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1"/>
        </MediaElement.RenderTransform>
</MediaElement>
```

I need to be able to load videos from anywhere in my computer but UWP cannot access all directories. I am loading video files through a button (code below). Long story short, I try to copy the file into the LocalAppData folder because I know I have permission to access files there.

**First Question:**
Can I copy files via CopyFileA() the way that I'm using it at the code below?

**Second Question**
After copying the file, I need to add it to my application's **Assets**. How can I do this via code?

Here is the code that I run when I try to load a file.

```
void SDKTemplate::Scenario4_ReproVideo::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    //This lines are here to get the path of the local folder of my app
    Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ f = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
    stdext::cvt::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> convert_local_path;
    Platform::String^ path_ss = f->Path;
    txtBlockOutput->Text = path_ss;
    std::string path_local = convert_local_path.to_bytes(path_ss->Data());



    FileOpenPicker^ fop = ref new FileOpenPicker();
    fop->SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId::Desktop;
    fop->FileTypeFilter->Append(".mp4");
    fop->FileTypeFilter->Append(".wmv");


    create_task(fop->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([this](StorageFile^ file) {
        if (file)
        {


            //We take the path of the file
            Platform::String^ path = file->Path;
            stdext::cvt::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> convert_path;
            std::string sourcePath = convert_path.to_bytes(path->Data());

            //We take the name of the file
            Platform::String^ name = file->Name;
            stdext::cvt::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> convert_name;
            std::string name_s = convert_name.to_bytes(name->Data());

            //We find out the local path (again) not sure if needed
            Platform::String^ path_ss = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path;
            stdext::cvt::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> convert_local_path;            
            std::string path_local = convert_local_path.to_bytes(path_ss->Data());

            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
            std::string sourceFile = sourcePath +"/" + name_s;
            std::string destFile = path_local +"/"+ name_s;

            if (CopyFileA(sourceFile.c_str(), destFile.c_str(), FALSE)) {
                txtBlockOutput->Text = "File is copied into local directory";
            }
            else { txtBlockOutput->Text = "File didn't copy"; }



            _media->Source = ref new Uri(destFile);
        }
        else
        {
            txtBlockOutput->Text = "Operation cancelled.";
        }
    });
```

Comment: "I try to copy the file into the LocalAppData folder because I know I have permission to access files there" - ehh, if you don't have access to read the file in its current location then obviously you will not be able to copy it either (copying implies *reading* the file from one location and then writing it elsewhere) - this seems rather pointless.

Comment: Pointless indeed but I am fairly new to this so I tried every solution I came up with.

Comment: If you use the `FileOpenPicker` then you have access to that `StorageFile` already. You don't need to copy it and you certainly don't need the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability. Is there a different problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With windows 10 version 1803, SDK build 17134, you can access all files that the user has access to using the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability.

On the other hand, your app has the permission to access the local LocalAppData location, you can access the file dirctly using the `ms-appdata` uri,

```
using Windows::Storage;
auto getFileTask = create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(ref new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt")));
getFileTask.then([](StorageFile^ file) 
{
    // Process file
});
```

So you don't need to copy the file to your application's Assets folder. Moreover, the application Assets folder is read only and is not writeable once deployed. you can not make any change in your app code including creating or copying file to this folder.

You should look into the document [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) to get more details about file access, and get the reference code from official [FileAccess](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess) code sample.

---Update to add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability ---

Firstly, right click the Package.appxmanifest file and select **View Code**, you will able to see the code in the manifest.

Secondly, in the top  tab, add the following code, `xmlns:rescap="..."` and put the `rescap` into the `IgnorableNamespaces` value, looks like `IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap"`, it will look like,

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

At last, add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability into the  tab,

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: BroadFileSystemAccess seems the best option for me. [Use of BFSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp) looking at this article I saw that I need to put some code into my Package.appxmanifest. I haven't found what to do afterwards. Do you know any documentation regarding this? As in your last link there isn't any examples using this nice new capability.

Comment: @CarlosHernandezPerez I have add the **Update** part in my reply to add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability to the manifest, you can refer it.

Comment: That was helpful, although I still get an error message when I add the broadFileSystemAccess capability, it says "The element Capabilities in name smape "http..." has a secondary elements in the namespace "rescap namespace full url" which is invalid.

Comment: @CarlosHernandezPerez The `broadFileSystemAccess` capability is a Restricted capabilities, When you add some restricted capabilities, the Visual studio underlines some information to warn it, it is not an error and you can build your app as usual. The Restricted capabilities are available for developers to use in their app, but require approval for store submission. See the [Restricted capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) to learn more about it.

Comment: It wasn't an error but a warning. Here is the explanation why for anyone interested. [Explanation of the warning]:(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/237538/error-in-packageappxmanifest-element-capabilities.html)

Comment: Yes, it is. This warning doesn't matter with your project, just ignore it. Please feel free to tell me if you still have any questions.

Comment: In fact I do. Once I've updated my Package.appxmanifest as you told me am I free to read any file? I am trying to display a video to a MediaElement using "ref new Uri(file->Path); but doesn't seem to work. "file" is a StorageFile^ type that I am taking using a FileOpenPicker^.

Comment: See the blog about path https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/. The `broadFileSystemAccess` capability  works for APIs in the [Windows.Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) namespace, such as [StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_GetFolderFromPathAsync_System_String_). Even you have the capability, you still need to use the speciafic api in Windows.Storage namespace to use the path.

Comment: It's not clear why you need the capability. You already have the `StorageFile` in your hand; why copy it? That wastes time and disk space. Even if you want to copy it, you don't need the capability for that (unless you really want to use Win32 APIs and not the `StorageFile` APIs).